# Vue.js cycle does not work

Tags: vue.js

Why shouldn't following code itterate 10 times building a model of 10 equal div's?

https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/50wL7mdz/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <div v-for="n in 10" id="example">
        <my-list-item></my-list-item>
    </div>
```

error from console: V-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements.

How do i fix it to get 10 different divs?

Comment: What about removing `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
new Vue({
    ...
    data: {
        ...
        desiredItemCount: new Array(10)
    },
    ...
});
```

And then use it in your template like this:

```
<div v-for="n in desiredItemCount" id="example">
    <my-list-item></my-list-item>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/69934/

Answer (score 0):

the vue instance you attached to should have only one root node. Since you are using `v-for` on the div with id example, 10 divs are created which have no root parent node.

So create a wrapper root node like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id=|example">
    <div v-for="n in 10">
        my-list-item></my-list-item>
    </div>
</div>
```